# Free energy Functional and its Relation to Pressure and Chemical Potential

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, pressure, units

I am reading a paper and trying to follow along some of the mathematical steps and reasoning; however, I can't quite understand one aspect. The authors give an expression for the free energy functional of the system:
$$ \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}[h,\psi,\nabla h,\nabla\psi] $$
which depends on the films thickness and the effective solute layer thickness.
Later on the authors use this to develop coupled evolution equations for $h$ and $\psi$ derived within the framework of gradient dynamics. What I don't quite understand is that in these coupled equations the authors define the total pressure, $p$, and the chemical potential, $\mu$, as:
$$ p = \frac{\delta\mathcal{F}}{\delta h} \quad\text{and}\quad \mu = \frac{\delta\mathcal{F}}{\delta \psi}  $$

Specifically, the units don't even seem to match up. The fundamental units of energy are $\frac{ML^2}{T^2}$ whereas for pressure they are $\frac{M}{LT^2}$. Given that $[h]=L$ how could the variational derivative of an energy functional possibly represent the total pressure?

Comment: For clarity and readability, please define your variables and identify the paper so that the context can be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the free energy in these functionals are in terms of energy density.

Here, because the functional deals with the film thickness, the free energy is most likely per unit surface area.

In that case $F\sim M/T^{2}$ and $p\sim F/h\sim M/LT^2$ as expected